# LDA in Opencv python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, lda

In OpenCV 2, how do we perform LDA analysis? I can see the C++ documentation but there seems to be nothing in Python.

`http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d59/classcv_1_1LDA.html`

Answer (score 1):

I saw a gentleman doing a great presentation last year on Machine Learning and Computer Vision for graduate students at a local university, demonstrating [**FruitClassification**](https://github.com/eliezerb/FruitClassification), a simple **Python** application that uses *scikit-learn* LDA implementation to classify Apples and Oranges. It was great!

I recently [**ported it to C++** to use **OpenCV**'s LDA implementation](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/cvFruitClassification).

Enjoy it!

Comment: It might not be a good way, but through this answer I found your profile.
Can you please have a look at this question :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497614/opencv-modifying-inpainting-to-achieve-proper-blur-in-image