# OpenCV : Modifying inpainting to achieve proper blur in image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to do some image processing for which I need to remove the facial features like eyes, nose, lips etc.
I have the following contour points

[image]

I am doing inpainting on this image::

[image]

Now I have to remove the facial features namely eyes, nose, lips and have the skin in place or that. The thing is that I don't have to do just for this image but for a general image that the user uploads.

I am trying using `inpainting` but it does create some problem, especially around lips where its having beards in neighbouring pixels and it gives a blackish output like this ::

[image]

I tried different contour points and shapes but somewhere or the other its causing problem mainly because of hair or beards. So how to achieve what I am trying to?

Code :: 
`Photo.inpaint(finalImage,imageROIGRAY,imageROIDest,8,Photo.INPAINT_NS);`

I have done dilation also on the mask, but doesn't work.

Showing mask for one of the shape formed using the contour points  ::

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to **blur** those regions before inpainting? How much of the face do you really need to preserve?

Comment: @karlphillip I have used various filters and median blur operations to achieve the cartoonised version of the actual image that you can see above. After that I am trying inpainting directly.

Comment: Can't you just blur the entire green region before doing inpaint?

Comment: @karlphillip I haven't tried but will that help, as I want to retain other features like skin color, shapes, cheekbones etc and just want to remove eyes, eyebrows, nose and lips.

Comment: In that case, it won't, so focus on getting rid of these small segments that are way darker than the average color of the face. A technique like this will probably preserve most of the facial features. Hold on, let's call @eliezer-bernart

Comment: @karlphillip Yeah I will try blurring and check that output, but I guess I will lose the beards and moustache in that case.

Comment: @karlphillip Can we have the color from one `roi` (like cheek) to the contours of another `roi` like lips?

Comment: The only way to answer those questions is to try and see what happens. It's up to you now. Good luck!

Comment: @karlphillip I meant is there any way in opencv to have the color of some other ROI of different size.